# H-264 mp4 video plays on an iPhone when embedded in a PDF via Acrobat, but not via media9

Tags: acrobat, media9

Is there a bug in the `media9` package that causes H-264 mp4 files to embed properly and play properly on a computer, but not an iPhone? I embedded the exact same mp4 video file in Acrobat X Pro (Mac OS 10.6.8) using the video tool under Multimedia, in which case the video played perfectly in Acrobat X Pro and ezPDF Reader on the iPhone. However, when I embedded the exact same video file via media9 (testing both `VPlayer.swf` and `StrobeMediaPlayback.swf`), the file played in Acrobat, but showed up as a blank media folder icon in ezPDF Reader. Clicking on that folder threw up an error message of

```
Media playback failure. Can not play format.
```

My LaTeX2e distribution is MacTeX 2012. I am using the LaTeX engine in TeXShop.

Comment: Interesting. I assumed Flash based video playback with Acrobat-9/X compatibility wouldn't work at all on an iPhone. Could you please send me or upload somewhere a minimal Acrobat-X generated example. (Use the mail address in the media9 documentation.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MP4/h.264 video and MP3 sound files embedded with `media9` version 0.11 are played back in ezPDF Reader on tablets and phones with Android or iOS, yet without using the Flash-based players (`StrobeMediaPlayback.swf`, `VPlayer.swf`, `APlayer.swf`) embedded along with the media file. ezPDF uses its own, built-in player because it doesn't support Flash.

In order to make video and sound files work in ezPDF Reader, they must be embedded without a path component in the file name. If media files reside in another directory than the current one `\addmediapath` should be used.

**Update:** Another requirement seems to be the omission of the playbuton overlay.

```
\addmediapath{path/to/media/files}
...
\includemedia[
  width=0.4\linewidth,height=0.3\linewidth,
  activate=pageopen,
  addresource=random.mp4,
  playbutton=none,
  flashvars={src=random.mp4}
]{}{StrobeMediaPlayback.swf}
```

Comment: This seems to be true also for playback in Acrobat itself, when I tried to add a path to the resource. The movie was able to play only in the machine I compiled (presumably it looked for the referred file in the filesystem rather than the embedded one.

Comment: I don't think so. I tested with a typical unix path `/home/...` and it played well on a Windows PC.

Comment: As we speak, I am trying with Linux (to compile) and Mac (to play) and it only works if I have the movie in the same path as the document (that is, I can include it without the full path). If I try to have the movie in some other location it doesn't play in the Mac. Not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: This amazes me, since the FlashPlayer plugin used by AR isn't allowed to access the local disk for file resources. On the Windows PC I use for viewing, the absolute `linux` path written into the PDF is definitely not valid.

Comment: Maybe I deactivated some security feature in the Acrobat (linux). I don't know, there are so many moving parts that it is easy to loose track.

Comment: I found the problem, I was adding the full path both to `addresource` and to `src`.

Comment: @alfC But this is correct! Flashvar `source`/`src` and option `addresource` must be given the same (full) path to the resource (media) file. Otherwise, the player cannot find the embedded file stream object in the PDF.

Comment: But it is in that case when if I try to play in the Mac (it was compiled in Linux) then it doesn't work. I have to move the file to the local directory and remove the full path and compile again to make it work in the Mac. Also, sorry to pestering, is there a way to reuse the flash resource for attachments?

Comment: @alfC This sounds really strange to me. `addresource` embeds the file as a stream object into the PDF, the file path is inserted into a so called name-tree together with the object number of the stream object. The Flashplayer gets the file path string, it has no notion of PDF objects numbers. The file path string is used to look up the file stream in the name-tree. In order to find it, the string in the name-tree and the string passed to the `source` must match. There is no access of the local hard disk in order to locate the file, the file path string is just used for look-up purposes.

Comment: @alfC As for embedded file attachments, I am working on it.

Comment: @alfC The recommended way is to use the `\addmediapath` macro. File resources don't need to reside in the current directory, if their path is registered in this way. Moreover, only the file base name is stored in the document which might appease faint-hearted/paranoid souls.