# AcroTeX on Android?

Tags: pdftex, android, acrotex

Does anyone know if the Acrotex bundle works on Android devices? Specifically, I would like to use the exerquiz package in conjunction with media9 to create interactive educational pdfs for Android (and possibly Apple) devices. I have already managed to make video play flawlessly on ezPDF in my Android phone ([H-264 mp4 video plays on an iPhone when embedded in a PDF via Acrobat, but not via media9](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66013/h-264-mp4-video-plays-on-an-iphone-when-embedded-in-a-pdf-via-acrobat-but-not-v/67224#67224)), and I'd like to make interactive quizzes using exerquiz - or any other package with the same functionality.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Cheers,

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: you can check if the examples [here](http://www.math.uakron.edu/~dpstory/webeq_ex.html) work on your android device (I got mixed result with mine).

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. Seems like exerquiz works with ezpdf reader, at least on my nexus 5. The example from the acrotex site do work, but a PDF that I made doesn't. Guess I'll have to check my LaTeX source code against the site's.

Comment: I have the same problem and I am very intereseted in a solution. I have tried only with Adobe Reader for android and my files based on exerquiz do not work. I'll have a look to the reader you suggest, but any other suggestion or workaround will be very appreciated.

Comment: Grames, looks like  Acrobat Reader for Android doesn't have the same functionality as the PC version, starting with embedded video through LaTeX's media9. I have searched a lot for workarounds, but to no avail. The only "workaround" that worked for me was buying ezPDF, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I cannot compell my users to buy ezPDF, but I'll give it a try.