# Animations in Beamer and iOS

Tags: beamer, animations, ipad

I've recently been using my iPad with TexPad to do a lot of tex work.  One thing that I do not know how to deal with is the issue of animations on the iPad, as my current method for embedding animations (usually mp4's) in the document is to use the media9 package which accomplishes this with flash.  Since iOS does not support flash, none of the standard PDF readers, including Acrobat, are capable of displaying the animation.  I was wondering if anyone had a strategy for putting animation in beamer in a way that the iPad can render it?

**Note**, I am really asking for alternatives to using a flash based solution entirely, rather than just querying how to run flash content on iOS.  I am open to using image sequences, other media formats, etc.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67224/36296

Comment: and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54595/36296

Comment: If your fine with image sequences, then you could use `\multiinclude`, see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240247/36296 (Not sure if the automatic frame change works with ios, but you could try it).

Answer (score 4):

You indicated that a sequence of images would be fine. In the spirit of your avatar image, I take the video from https://www.eso.org/public/videos/eso50supernova/ for the following example.

> 1. Converting mp4 to a series of images

There are many tools out there, one possibility is to use `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:04 -t 00:10 -i eso50supernova.mp4 -r 1 image-%d.jpeg
```

This configuration will give you one image per second. For the selected time frame this makes 13 images called `image-1.jpeg` etc. For a higher image rate, adjust the value for `-r`.

> 2. Using these images in beamer

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xmpmulti}
\begin{document}

    %asuming you images are called "image-1.jpeg" up to "image-13.jpeg" 
    \begin{frame}
        \transduration<0-13>{0}
        \multiinclude[<+->][format=jpeg,start=1, graphics={width=\textwidth}]{image}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

> 3. Viewing

Try with acrobat in presentation mode for the automatic slide change. Based on experience with OSX, apples pdf viewer is not capable to do the automatic changing.